# How to Reload Data in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm using UITableView To display content by using web Services. I need to reload data once every minute.  Can any one help me to do this...

Comment: have u tried any thing on your self so for or from below answers.please accept any answer from below answers.

Answer (score 4):

There are two questions:

1) How to reload `UITableView` cells?

2) How to do it automatically every 60 seconds?

My answers:

1) To reload data manually you should have pointer on your `UITableView` instance. You could do it using `@property` and `IBOutlet` by connecting your table with this property. Assume that you named it `tableView`. Then you could just call `[tableView reloadData];` to reload all cells and sections of table.

2) The simplest way is to create `NSTimer` that will fire every 60 seconds and call particular method. For example:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 target:self selector:@selector(updateTable) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

P.S. Also you could reload particular cell(s) or section(s) of table view. Please, search in Apple Docs for them

Answer (score 1):

Write a method containing code that loads data from web service and calls `[tableView reloadData]`. Then create a [timer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) and make it call the method every minute.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Set the NSTimer of 1 minute in ViewdidLoad Method of View Controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(reloadTable) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

// reload Table Method

-

```
(void)reloadTable{
 [self.tableView reloadData];
[myTimer invalidate];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 target:self selector:@selector(TblUpdate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)TblUpdate
{

//Your Webservice

//table reload
    [tbl reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 /*****TIMER*****/
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTable) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


/******************************************************************************/
-(void)updateTable{
   [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Halley's answer, or you could make the timer call reloadData to the tableview itself.

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 target:self.tableView selector:@selector(reloadData) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to check your data model every time. to just reload the table view with the same data with some interval is not good idea. right ?

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateData) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)updateData {
  //do something with data model
  //and reload table then
  [self.tableView reloadData];
 }
```